# Page-alias without .html-suffix

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, typo3

One TYPO3 installation I have here uses the field `alias` in the page settings. **It does not make use of `simulatestatic` or `realurl`**. If the alias of a page is to `foo`, this page is reachable under the following URLs:

- `/index.php?id=foo`
- `/foo.html`

I now want the page to be reachable under an additional URL: `/foo`, without the `.html`.

My approach was to simply use mod_rewrite add some rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
```

My RewriteRules work, they rewrite the URI `/foo` first to `/foo.html` and later to `/index.php`. This does not work, I get a 404 when requesting `/foo`.

I assume this happens since TYPO3 still gets the info that the original URI was `/foo` instead of `/foo.html`, which it doesn't recognize.

How could this be solved, without using realurl or simulatestatic (the side-effects are unwanted), and without using a HTTP redirect (the URL in the browser should be `/foo`)? Is there something like a server-internal redirect in apache?

Comment: Are you sure simulate static isn't on? I didn't know about "alias" before, but http://www.jochenfroehlich.com/typo3-glossar/alias.html tells me the described behaviour is achieved with simulatestatic. If not, maybe its a custom extension you could extend?

Comment: No, simulatestatic is off, I'm sure of that. If it were on, Menus would for example generate URLs ending with `.html` (page type and id coded into the file name), but the generated URLs look like `index.php?id=alias`. This problem has since been worked around (but not solved) by using mod_rewrite to append `.html` to URIs without slashes dots (= no file extension) and then redirect the client via HTTP.

Comment: Which "side-effects" are unwanted? Are there negative ones?

Comment: Yes, but they are of category "business". Can't go into details, sorry. If these were not existent, realurl would have been installed a long time ago

Answer (score 1):

If [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) is activated on your server, you could use the [proxy flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) [P] and write:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1.html [QSA,P]
```

If not, you could write a php file that acts as a proxy (I've done that before for Typo3). cURL oder even a simple file_get_contents() is very handy in this case. Make sure to only load pages from your domain. Redirect your non-.html files to the proxy file that redirects them to the .html-file which is then processed by Typo3.